# CUDA Error: resource already mapped while running darknet

Tags: google-colaboratory, darknet

I'm running darknet on colab and getting this error after 20 epochs.

```
CUDA Error: resource already mapped
darknet: ./src/cuda.c:36: check_error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Is it a memory issue? I saw other errors of CUDA running out of memory on GitHub but this wasn't there.